# List of EF objects to Dictionary of lists using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I'd like to convert a list of EF objects to a dictionary. I somewhat accomplished this, with one drawback: I can't figure out how to add multiple of the objects to one `key,value` pair based on an attribute of that object.

For example say I have an Entity Framework object `TblValue` with three values - `ValueID, ValueNm, CodeID`.

The `CodeID` will be shared among the objects - some may be the same and some may be different.

I would like to create a `Dictionary<TblCode, List<TblData>>`. (`TblCode` comes from `CodeID`.) Basically, I want to create a dictionary of this list of items where each list is separated & grouped by the `CodeID`, using LINQ.

The LINQ statement I was using before was working, but it wouldn't do any grouping. Is this pretty close, or is LINQ not appropriate for this? Would a `foreach` loop be better?

`var splitTimes = times.Cast<TblValue>().ToDictionary(o => tr.GetCode(o.CodeID));`

**clarification** - I am unable to group the values....I cannot create a `Dictionary<TblCode, List<TblValue>>`, I can only create a `Dictionary<TblCode, TblValue>`

Comment: Looks like an XY  Problem.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem You presenting a solution to a problem, but what is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: edited for clarification...does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it, the_joric's answer was close but I had to explicitly call `ToList()` on the values.

`var splitTimes = times.GroupBy(x => x.ProjCdId).ToDictionary(o => tr.GetProjCd(o.Key), o => o.ToList());`

Answer (score 3):

You need to first group and then convert to dictionary. Like that:

```
var dictionary = tblValues
      .GroupBy(table => table.CodeID)
      .ToDictionary(values => values.Key);
```

If you need to convert you key do it in either `GroupBy()` or `ToDictionary()`